# Крэш приложения после возвращения по средством dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Периодически через раз, после возвращения на первый контроллер по средством кнопки на втором контроллере

```
@IBAction func closeButton(sender: UIButton) {
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

пытаясь нажать на любую кнопку первого контроллера приложение зависает и перекидывает в апделегат с ошибкой. при краше в логах нет сообщения об ошибке. На симуляторе и на девайсе приложение остается включено, но зависшее, кнопки не реагируют.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На лишние аутлеты проверил, лишнего нет. краш происходит после возращения только с одного контроллера. Этот же метод использую и на др контроллерах, но краша никогда не происходило. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А можно хоть немного больше информации? Что в первом контроллере, что во втором? Точно ничего не пишет об ошибке?

Comment: На первом контроллере просто  UIButton по нажатию на которую совершается переход на второй контроллер через Present Modally. На втором контролле тоже просто UIButton, по нажатию на которую возвращаемся на первый экран, экшн описал выше. На первом экране есть еще вторая кнопка, по нажатию на которую переходим на третий экран через Show. Приложение зависает иногда, когда только вернулись со второго экрана, не успев нажать больше никакой кнопки, а бывает после возвращения когда нажимаешь на кнопку перехода на третий экран. В логах точно ничего не пишет

Comment: предположу, что контроллер выгружается из памяти, и при попытке вью отправить что либо контроллеру происходит крэш.

Comment: Это как то можно исправить?пример ниже не помог

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить такую праверку:

```
if([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(closeButton:)
                           withObject:nil
                       waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: все равно ошибка осталась